# Remove selected items from $_POST / $_SESSION array

Tags: php

I am posting from a form that selects products from a list, to a page with the selected products displayed. I want to have a link next to each item for removing an item from the selected list (array).

How do I do that? I seem to be losing the session once I click on the remove link.

```
session_start();

foreach($_SESSION['id'] as $key => $value){

      $array = explode(',', $value);

      if($value[0]!=''){
        $id = $array[0];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $product_id = $row['id'];

            echo '<tr valign="bottom">';
            echo '<td>' . stripslashes($row['category']) . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . stripslashes($row['itemDesc']) . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td class="right">' . stripslashes(number_format($row['points'], 2)) . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=remove&key=' . $key . '&s=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '">Remove</a></td>';
            echo "</tr>\n\n";
            $points = stripslashes($row['points']);
            @$points_total += $points;
          }
      }
      }


$postid = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

$product_id = htmlspecialchars(@$_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');//the product id from the URL
$s = $_SESSION['id'];
$s = htmlspecialchars(@$_GET['key'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');//the product id from the URL
$action = htmlspecialchars(@$_GET['action'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //the action from the URL

switch($action) {
    case "remove":
        unset($array[$id]); //remove $product_id from the array with
        echo $action . $product_id;
break;
    }
```

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
 <form method="post" action="products_selected.php">
<?php

  $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rangeCode, category ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $id = $row['id'];

    echo '<tr valign="bottom">';
    echo '<td>' . stripslashes($row['rangeCode']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . stripslashes($row['category']) . '</a></td>';
    echo '<td>' . stripslashes($row['itemDesc']) . '</a></td>';
    echo '<td>' . number_format($row['points'], 2) . ' points ';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' . $id . '" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>' . "\n\n";
  }
  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
 <tr><td colspan=13><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the HTML code for the form? Thanks

Comment: @Erenor I edited the question to include the form HTML

Comment: @Grant have you tried `unset($array[$product_id]);` ? BTW those `@` are pretty ugly, try to use `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` :)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV - Yes, I tried unset($array[$product_id]); it gives me the same result, loses the $_SESSION['id']

Comment: Am I losing the $_SESSION['id'] on reload of the page because I have session_start(); at the top of the page? So it starts a new session every page load? I tried to move it to the initial form page but does that not change anything.

Comment: Try changing `echo '<td><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=remove&key=' . $key . '&s=' . $_SESSION['id'] . '">Remove</a></td>';` to `echo '<td><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=remove&key=' . $key . '&s=' . $product_id . '">Remove</a></td>';`

Comment: No, the `session_start()` re-starts the session, it's there exactly for what we need: remember something (or someone) between page loads and reloads

Comment: OK amended to: echo '<td><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?action=remove&key=' . $key . '&s=' . $product_id . '">Remove</a></td>'; But shows same result loses Session.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a comment, but forgot to press "Add comment", and was waiting for your answer.. *facepalm* :D Anyway, i was asking you to check the content of session right after the `session_start()` with the command `var_dump($_SESSION);`. If it's an empty array after a refresh of the page, the session is getting lost , so you have a problem there. If, instead, it contains something, then the problem is somewhere else in the code, and we will find it :)

Comment: :) No worries! I really appreciate your input. OK I added var_dump($_SESSION) after session_start() and get the following: array(1) { ["id"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "9" [3]=> string(2) "27" [4]=> string(2) "33" [5]=> string(3) "552" } }

Comment: Looks like its not losing the $_SESSION

Comment: Ok, the session is working, so we are ok on that side (it contains the items). Let me try a live example, to see some things :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25963/discussion-between-erenor-paz-and-grant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. After a bit of chat and co-working around this issue, we found some problems.

1. There's the need to insert a check around the code that uses $_GET and $_POST data, to avoid unwanted modification to other variables (an example: when the user clicks "Remove" to remove an item from his choices, the $_SESSION array will be updated with the $_POST array; since this contains nothing, the session array is emptied (and this was why the session was thought to be lost):
2. To find and delete the item from the session, we have to use the key retrieved from url and check if it's present into the session array. This can be seen in the code below.

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['id']))
   { 
     $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']; 
   } 

   if(isset($_GET['key']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'remove'))
   { 
     if (array_key_exists($_GET['key'], $_SESSION['id']))
     { 
       unset($_SESSION['id'][$_GET['key']]); 
     } 
   }
   ```

Some other minor changes have been made to the code, but the main problems were the ones explained.